# Accessing Azure App Proxy service from SharePoint Online

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I am working on validating whether we can access an internal on-prem service, exposed externally via Azure App Proxy, in a client side code.

Structure of things
1. An internal service
2. Azure App Proxy exposing the internal service externally
3. A SharePoint Online Page - On this page I am trying to validate whether I can access the service via app proxy

Flow
1. User signs-in to the SharePoint Online site
2. Navigates to a page that pulls data from azure app proxy service
3. User should see data from internal service passed over through Azure App Proxy without any authentication challenge

Is the above flow possible? I tried the same and it fails where the call to Azure App Proxy is stopped with status code 307. I suspect the call is deemed as unauthenticated and hence failing.

Had a look at the various cookies passed when I access SharePoint Online - FedAuth and rtfa

Had a look at the various cookies passed when I access Azure App Proxy directly and once authenticated by login - AzureAppProxyUserSessionCookie, ASP.NET_SessionId, AzureAppProxyAccessCookie

Considering there are different set of cookies for each authenticated session, I am doubtful, the desired flow is plausible.

Comment: The `307` redirection is expected and it is not relative to the authentication issue. The Azure AD will redirect this request to the Azure app proxy(refer [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/applicationproxyblog/2015/11/09/azure-ad-application-proxy-http-to-https-redirection/)). To narrow down this issue, you may need to check whether the Azure app proxy work well by refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-troubleshoot).

Comment: Thanks Fei. Azure App proxy is working fine. So if I access it directly in a browser by using it's url, I get authentication challenge. Post authentication, I am successfully able to see the results from app proxy. I want the same facility to work from within client side code.

Comment: Would you mind sharing more detail about the **client side code** means? Based on my understanding, the Azure app proxy need to work with HTTP/HTTPS protocol( refer [Application Proxy prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-enable)).

Comment: It's a jQuery ajax call from a SharePoint Online web page to Azure App proxy URL.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Azure app proxy only allowed the pre-authentication user. For this mean, Azure app proxy requires the token issued from Azure AD for the authentication. And when you initiate the request from the jQuery ajax call from a SharePoint online page, it doesn't contain the token it required.

So, it depends on if it is possible to acquire the token from your AJAX call before you send the request. You can try to capture the request for the authentication request, and construct the request in a hide IFrame to see whether it is possible to simulate the progress to get the token.

More detail about connectors please refer the link below:

[How to provide secure remote access to on-premises applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-get-started)

And for the security considerations, this document is helpful:

[Security considerations for accessing apps remotely with Azure AD Application Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-proxy-security-considerations)